# mvn build outputting build contents to working directory

Tags: java, maven

The following pom file is generating build contents to the working directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLframetion="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.blahblah.orgname.appname</groupId>
<artifactId>blahblah-appname-homepage</artifactId>
<version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<description>home page application</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <start-class>com.blahblah.orgname.appname.homepage.Application</start-class>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.2</org.aspectj-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.blahblah.frame.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>frame-logging-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                <releaseProfiles>releases</releaseProfiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install (initialize)</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm dist (prepare-package)</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>run-script</argument>
                            <argument>dist</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                <configuration>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.blahblah.frame.logging</groupId>
                            <artifactId>frame-logging-core</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        exec-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.3.2,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>exec</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<!-- SCM START: Plug in your git repository urls here before publishing
    your app <scm> <url>[GIT_HTTPS_URL]</url> <connection>scm:git:[GIT_SSH_URL]</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:[GIT_SSH_URL]</developerConnection> <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm> SCM END -->
```

before:

```
/src
```

after:

```
/src
/com
/org
/junit
```

I would like it to output to a 'build' folder so that it can be easily cleaned.  I've tried adding a outputDirectory tag, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maven does that by default. It looks like you're fiddled with something else here. Are you perhaps compiling this in Eclipse without having imported it with m2e?

Comment: <outpublahblahirectory>?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo That's a typo when i was editing it for posting.  I've fixed it now thanks.

Comment: @chrylis I'm compiling from the command line.  'mvn install'

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify it in the build section like this:

```
<build>
    <directory>output</directory>
</build>
```

Comment: I tried adding the directory tag just now and it doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Turns out in your settings.xml file you must add the following:

```
<localRepository>C:\PATH_YOU_WANT\.m2\repository</localRepository>
```

By default the localRepository is set to the folder of the build.